# Listen click events if iframe containing a PDF in angular

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I have a div that contains an iframe based on a variable. The iframe either contains html link or the PDF.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="pp-content" #ppContent>
  <!-- PDF -->
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="PREVEW_TYPE.PDF">
    <iframe id="documentPreviewPDF" [src]="previewUrls[0] | sanitizeUrl" scrolling="no" *ngIf="previewUrls">
    </iframe>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- HTML -->
  <div *ngSwitchCase="PREVEW_TYPE.HTML" style="height: 100%;">
     <iframe id="documentPreviewHTML" [src]="previewUrls[0] | sanitizeUrl" *ngIf="previewUrls">
     </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is how I am attaching the click event:

```
@ViewChild("ppContent", { static: true })
ppContent: ElementRef;

private _listenClickOnIframe(): void {
    if (this.ppContent) {
        const iframe = this.ppContent.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
        if (iframe) {
            iframe.onload = () => {
                iframe.contentWindow.document.onclick = this._closeChannelListDD;
            };
        }
    }
}

private _closeChannelListDD(): void {
    console.log("Click");
}
```

Based on a button preview type is changed and `_listenClickOnIfram` method is called.

This is working if preview type is html but in case of PDF click event is not working?

Comment: well.. you should also share the part of code that change the type (html / pdf) as well.. maybe there is a configuration problem with your `PREVEW_TYPE` enum

Comment: @ymz it just switch the view, and it works, I mean new iframe gets created and shows pdf

Comment: still.. lots of information is missing here... such as: what is the value of `ppContent` when you try to load pdf? It's really hard to inspect the problem without more code

Comment: @ymz question updated